# Error 1053 after starting a Windows service

Tags: c#, service

I created a Windows Service installed with InstallUtil and started using the Services app ... I finally receive this error

[image]

[image]

But from this Log screen tells me that the service has started (in my service is a message that I write after it is connected to my databases)
[image]

But on the services app the state is always "starting", I can not stop it because the service says "I can not receive messages"

This is Program.cs class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new InterCompanyService()
            };
#if DEBUG
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

                foreach (var serviceBase in ServicesToRun)
                {
                    var serviceType = serviceBase.GetType();
                    var methodInfo = serviceType.GetMethod("OnStart", bindingFlags);

                    new Thread(service => methodInfo.Invoke(service, new object[] { args })).Start(serviceBase);
                }

                return;
            }
#endif
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
```

Class Service

```
public InterCompanyService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            EventSourceCreationData escd = new EventSourceCreationData(eventLog.Source, eventLog.Log);

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventLog.Source))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(escd);
            }
        }
```

In OnStart I try to connect via EntityFramework to my DB

Comment: We need to know what the errors are.  I.e. in English.

Comment: The service "name" does not start "error 1053: "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Comment: this could be because of an error that is encountered in code written in the OnStart() function of Service.

Comment: pull420 I change the answer with more info

Comment: I Found solution It was enough to install the .exe file in Release mode